# Dentro de un foreach meter otra query

Tags: php, html

Estoy sacando datos de la SQL en una tabla. Realizo un foreach para que me saque todos los resultados. Un campo de la tabla pedidos se llama categoría donde guardo un numero que identifica la categoría con una tabla que se llama categorías. Entonces inteno sacar los nombres de las categorías no el número.

```
    <tbody>
       <?php
         $analisis = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM analisis WHERE tipoprueba = 1");
         foreach ($analisis as $ana){
       ?>
         <tr class="dato_tabla tabza dato_tabla odd">
            <td class="otrotdfgaz"><?php echo $ana['id']; ?></td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz"><?php echo $ana['strsiglas']; ?></td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz" style="font-weight: 700;"><?php echo $ana['strnombre'];?></td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz"><?php echo $ana['strprecio']; ?></td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz">
             <?php
               $categorias = $mysqli->query("SELECT ana.categoria, cat.id_categoria, cat.categoria
               from analisis as ana
               INNER JOIN categorias as cat ON ana.categoria = cat.id_categoria");
               if($cate = $categorias->fetch_array()){}
             ?>
                <?php echo $cate['categoria']; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz center">
               <?php if ($ana['estado'] == 0 ){
                echo "<span class=\"usDesctiva\">Desactivado</span>";
                }else {
                echo "<span class=\"usActivado\">Activado</span>";
                } ?>
            </td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz center">
              <a href=""><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="<?php echo $ana['id']; ?>" class="borrar_dato"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
             </td>
            </tr>
           <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
```

En la segunda query es donde tengo el problema, me saca todo el rato la misma categoría, no se si es por estar dentro de un `foreach` entonces me repite todo el rato la misma.

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: En análisis cual es la columna con la que relacionas dicha tabla con categorías?

Comment: columna categoria de analisis , con id_categoria de la tabla categorias @BetaM

Comment: no es una buena practica enfocar el problema como lo estas haciendo. usa un join entre la tabla analisis y la tabla categoria y te traes la columna de la tabla categoria que necesites

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta @Francisco pudes poner el ejemplo como una respuesta???

Comment: bueno una pregunta, un analisis pertenece a mas de una categoria??

Comment: no en este casol solo pertenece a una categoría

Answer (score 1, accepted):

voy a tratar de escribir mas o menos un seudocod:

```
<?php
$analisisQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT analisis.id, analisis.strsiglas, analisis.strnombre, analisis.strprecio, categoria.nombre as categoriaNombre FROM analisis INNER JOIN categoria ON analisis.categoria_id = categoria.id WHERE analisis.tipoprueba = 1");
$resultados=$analisisQuery->fetch_array();
foreach($resutados as $registro){?>
   <tr class="dato_tabla tabza dato_tabla odd">
            <td class="otrotdfgaz"><?php echo $registro['id']; ?></td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz"><?php echo $registro['strsiglas']; ?></td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz" style="font-weight: 700;"><?php echo $registro['strnombre'];?></td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz"><?php echo $registro['strprecio']; ?></td>
            <td class="otrotdfgaz">
             <?php

             ?>
                <?php echo $registro['categoriaNombre']; ?>
            </td>
```

bueno, es mas o menos la idea, incluir en la consulta las columnas que deseas mostrar en la vista y obtener el resultado como un array asociativo, no recuerdo excactmaente la funcion php de la extension mysql pero la idea es esa.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he cambiado los datos para dejarlo con mis datos de tablas, pero me arroja que no hay ningún resultado @Francisco  publico repuesta para que me corrijas, gracias

Comment: Edito, solo tuve que cambiar un campo más y funciona correcto. Te dejo abajo el detalle. Gracias @Francico

Answer (score 0):

Publico mi respuesta pero no solución, no me arroja datos:

```
  $analisis = $mysqli->query("SELECT analisis.id, analisis.strsiglas, analisis.strnombre, analisis.strprecio, categorias.id_categoria, categorias.categoria as categoriaNombre 
    FROM analisis INNER JOIN categorias ON analisis.categoria = categorias.id_categoria 
    WHERE analisis.tipoprueba = 1");
    foreach ($analisis as $ana){
```

Comment: Corrijo, solo cambie nombre por categoria y funciona, pero marcar la mia como respuesta valida no es lo justo, voy a poner la de francisco como buena @BetaM que creo que se entendera igual

Comment: Ya la marque y se lo comente a el, gracias!

Comment: Gracias, es que escribí una idea y seguro que algún error puede existir,qué bueno sirvió!!!